# XML error: Prefix not bound to a namespace, KML file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, kml, xml-namespaces

So I'm attempting to repair a KML file from my boss. For those who know these are just XML files really, so I'm working off a copy I renamed to XML and using Firefox to validate. I get this error:

> XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace Location:
>   file:///home/user/Desktop/myplaces.broken-19-11-2019.xml Line Number
>   942553, Column 3:
>   `<Document id="NEC"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2
>   http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd
>   http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2
>   http://code.google.com/apis/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd">`

I am not a developer, but I have been around for some time. Below, is the lien in question along with the 1 before and the 1 after to help give context.  What can I do to help resolve this?

```
</Folder>
<Document id="NEC" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2 http://code.google.com/apis/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd">
    <name>NEC</name>
```

Here is the first couple of lines in the file as well since I've seen those might be relevant:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML namespace prefixes such as `xsi:` must be defined.

Simply add

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

to your `kml` element to eliminate that error:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
     xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
     xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
     xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: You might talking over my head just a bit.  When you say add it to the KML element you mean it needs to be within the <kml> </kml> tags yes?

Comment: No, add as you would an attribute.   Answer updated to show where.

Comment: Wait, I figured it out. I pasted that into the <kml ...> line.  Refreshed and works!  Thank you!